# For Images document library, set the default content type to Image

Tags: 2010, document-library, content-type

Is there any way to have the default content type set to Image when uploading the Images document library?

It would be nice to remove the extra step of changing `Document` to `Image`

[image: screencap]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Library Settings click "Change new button order and default content type" and set "Image" to be number 1 (that's the one used as default):
[image]

Comment: It did change the order, but it's still showing Document as the default even though I have Image set. I also tried unchecking everything but Image, but for some reason, Document is still the default and is still showing up. Are you also seeing this behaviour?

Comment: No, when I change the default it works on uploads. (My Images library doesn't have Documents and you can delete it if you don't want to use it)

Comment: Hmm weird.. I am having the same issue as this [post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/cbdca58a-0c08-4a9f-9ace-e6547128ce2c/how-to-set-default-content-type-for-document-library-folder-?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

Comment: OH nevermind, you're right. I previously uploaded my image as a document, and when I tried to reupload, it was already set. That's why I was seeing it as a document.